# Streamlit: Disable the guard against running files without a .py extension?

Tags: streamlit

I have a problem.  Universally, my experience working in Unix systems has been that, by the time you are ready to place an executable "thing" in a bin folder for global access, you have decided to `#!` the file with the requisite interpreter:

```
#!/bin/awk
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/perl
#!/bin/python3.8
#!/bin/whatever
```

And, although it is fine to have clutter at the local scope, when one places an executable in the bin folder, it should have:

- A POSIX CLI interface
- No discernible language tags or what have you

This is because it is now intended to be used for difficult work that requires forgetting about the details of this or that language: one *now* needs to think in terms of the functions *as if* the composable units are part of a consistent language, rather than a dozen different languages from a dozen different expert contributors.

This is the "genius" of the Unix/Linux/Posix architecture.

---

Anyways, when structuring my python projects, the end game is copying python executables to a global source on the path -- whether that "global" source is a pretend global source in my home directory (i.e., `~/.mytools/bin` or the actual global path, `/usr/bin` or something like that -- and generally I want my python executables to have the same "game feel" as C executables, perl executables, BASH/ZSH/etc. executables.

In that vein, I knock off the extensions from my scripts and executables when they go in the bin.  There is no need to know, from my usage perspective, what anything is made of when I go to use it.

---

However, streamlit requires me to re-append the `.py` to the file in the global path in order to run with `streamlit run`.  This is a case of the library reaching up out of its useful value and holding me hostage, from my perspective,  unless I violate best practices when extending the bin folder with python executables.

This means I have to create special logic to handle just streamlit, and that is really a kerfluffle. I have to either: change the way I handle all executables, or hardcode just the executable that will be run with streamlit.  That means that, all of a sudden, I have an arbitrary name in my meta-control code for my project.

That is bad. Why? because I have to remember that I did it, and remember to change it if I change the executable name.  I also have to remember to add to it if I add another streamlit executable.

---

Alternatively, I can copy all my exes made with python into the root bin folders with their `.py` extensions, which is not what I wanted to do.

How does one bypass this issue in streamlit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `bin/sometool` needs to be invoked with Streamlit via `streamlit run bin/sometool`, it seems like you're already exposing "meta-control code" to users of your bin script, right?

Instead, would this solve your problem?

`bin/sometool`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$(dirname "$0")
streamlit run "$DIR"/the_actual_script.py
```

(Where `the_actual_script.py` sits inside bin, but has `chmod -x` so that it's not directly executable.)